# Java: How to set up a 2D character array in which certain characters are designated to only occupy a percentage of the grid?

Tags: java, arrays, string, character

Good evening everyone,
I have a problem in which I have to print a grid array occupied by three characters (X, O, and a blank space " "). These characters are designated by the user to only occupy a certain percentage (X and O will always be equal). 
I'm not very sharp on arrays, so I'm not exactly sure how to appraoch the problem array-wise, or if arrays are even necessary in this case.

I've approached the problem by incorporating Math.Random and using a sort of case system via if's to go about it. My problem is I'm not entirely sure how to limit the characters' printing.

> public static void assignCellTypes(char[][] tissue, int percentBlank, int percentX){

```
    int n = 5;
    int i;
    int j;
    char[][] box = new char [n][n];
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    int c = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) { 
        for ( j = 0; j< n;  j++) {
            double q  = Math.random();
            if (q >= .5 && a <= percentBlank) {
                System.out.print(" ");
                a = a + 1;

            }else if (q <= .5 && q >= .25 && b/(n*n) <= percentX) {

                System.out.print("O");
                b = b + 1;
            } else if (q <= .25 && c/(n*n) <= percentX) {
                System.out.print("X");
                c = c + 1;
            }
        }
        } System.out.println();

    }
```

As per stackoverflow's rules and general etiquette, I just want to already put out there that I'm not looking for anyone to put out the answer to this problem in particular. I just want to know if there's a format or a couple of different approaches I can use to incorporate such a thing, and maybe a little tip or two to help me wrap my head around the array part of this problem. 
Any help with this would be greatly appreciated, as I've been trying to work through this intently for a few days now but haven't come up with much of anything but this. Thank you for your time in advanced.

Comment: As I see it, you can work in 2 ways: 
1. Storing values in the array `box[][]` and then print. 
2. Directly to the console output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you can do is:

n = 5, so the matrix is 5 x 5 then 25 items will be stored.

If percentX = 30% then itemsX = (int) Math.rint ((n * n) * (percentX / 100))

If percentBlank = 40% then itemsBlank = (int) Math.rint ((n * n) * (percentBlank / 100))

So we can calculate itemsO = (n * n) - (itemsBlank + itemsX)

This will give you the number of items that you will have for each type X, O or Blank in the matrix.

You must initialize the counters:

```
     int countBlank int = 0; 
     int countX = 0;
     int countO = 0;
```

We get the kind of character X, O or Blank randomly. 
We use:

```
 int q = (int) (Math.random ()*3);
```

This will return an integer between 0 and 2 inclusive ->  [0, 1, 2]

```
if (q == 0) { // We obtained a Blank, add +1 to the counter and store or print to the console the character ' '
   if (countBlank < itemsBlank) {
       System.out.print("' ' "); // Or box[i][j]=' '
       countBlank +=1;
   } else {
       j-=1; // If the quota is reached Blank, subtract 1 from j to try to get other character in that position in the array.   
   }                        
} 
if (q == 1) { // We obtained a 'O'
    if (countO < itemsO) {
       System.out.print("'O' ");
       countO+=1;
    } else {
       j-=1;
    }    
}
if (q == 2) { // We obtained a 'X'
    if (countX < itemsX) {
       System.out.print("'X' ");
       countX+=1;
    } else {
       j-=1;
    }    
}
```

Comment: This was a huge help for me, even with the first entry that told me to break down the characters to a quantity of items. I ended up designing a similar quota system that used Math.Random, and it came out to be very close to this in terms of logic.

Comment: Thank you very much! (didn't mean to hit Enter and send that comment so early).